# How to use lapply to do t.testing

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, na

I am wondering how to use apply/lapply/sapply, or for looping to do t.testing.

I have a set of 2 level grouping variables and a set of numeric variables within the same dataframe.

For example the dataframe would look something like this:

```
df<-

Var1  Var2      Group1  Group2
Na    6    …    TRUE    TRUE
1     9    …    FALSE   FALSE
3     5    …    TRUE    TRUE
Na    Na   …    FALSE   FALSE
3     2    …    TRUE    TRUE
4     5    …    FALSE   FALSE
Na    1    …    FALSE   TRUE
21    2    …    TRUE    FALSE
19    3    …    FALSE   FALSE
12    7    …    TRUE    TRUE
```

with 10 numeric variables and 10 grouping variables. The main problem is the NAs in the data, which I can't figure out how to ignore.

```
for (i in 1:10){
    for (j in 11:20){
        print(t.test(df[i],df[j])$p.value, na.rm = TRUE)
        }
    }
```

where the i's are my numeric variables and the j's are my grouping variables.

The idea is that I want to compare all numeric variables against all grouping variables but this code results in the error:

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my)))
stop("data are essentially constant") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(y) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In var(y) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I just need to ignore NAs basically. I am not familiar with lapply or apply but i know that within R they tend to be much simpler than running loops.

Please let me know if there is an easy solution for this.

Ultimately I don't want to do tons of t.tests one by one...

Thanks,
-A

Comment: `for (i in 1:5) for (j in 6:10) print(t.test(mtcars[i], mtcars[j])$p.value)` works so the issue must be your data, since you didnt post it, we can't be much more help

Comment: If you have a grouping variable `group`, and want to test whether elements of a vector `vec` that correspond to one group are different in mean from those that correspond to another group the syntax is `t.test(vec, by=group)`. If you write `t.test(vec, group)` it will compare the mean value of `vec` to the mean value of `group`

Comment: @GabrielFGeislerMesevage t.test doent have a by argument so that gets ignored `identical(t.test(sleep$extra, by = sleep$group), t.test(sleep$extra))` is true

Comment: You're right, what I wrote was incorrect. I won't delete it so your comment remains coherent. The correct syntax would be `t.test(vec[group==0], vec[group==1])`, or whatever the levels are called. But including the grouping variable as the `y` vector in the argument looks like what is generating the problem.

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the commend so far, I am still running into the problem with the NAs but I have edited my question to include an example dataset and a clearer question.